# Does leaving a tooth in coke overnight dissolve it?

Tags: drinks

I've been told that leaving a tooth in coca cola or other sodas overnight will cause the tooth to dissolve, or at least partially dissolve.

Is this true, and is drinking coke therefore a hazard to to the health of your teeth?

Comment: Regardless or not this specific claim is true, [certainly drinking coke damages the teeth](http://www.healthline.com/health/dental-oral-health/what-does-soda-do-to-your-teeth).

Comment: You put two claims in this question.  Soaking a tooth in coke dissolves it and drinking coke is bad for your teeth.  Which one do you want answered?

Comment: @Brythan both, they are related enough to be grouped together

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/does-diet-soda-cause-tooth-decay/6195#6195

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does (diet) soda cause tooth decay?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/does-diet-soda-cause-tooth-decay)

Answer (score 5):

A tooth will not decay overnight in sodas. Yes, Sodas contain acid, but nowhere strong enough for that effect!
Among others, [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/cokelore/tooth.asp) debunked it.
There is a risk from sodas (as well as at least some juices) for your teeth, from both sugar and acids (See [here](http://www.livescience.com/44081-does-sugar-cause-cavities-plaque.html)), but nothing as drastic or imminent as dissolving teeth overnight.

Comment: Even if it did, there's a collosal scaling error there. (disclaimer: back-of-the-envelope-math) When you drink coke or any other acidic soda, the liquid generally spends less than a second in your mouth (and thus in contact with your teeth) per 1oz sip. You'd need to drink on the order of 288000 oz in total to match the same exposure as an eight-hour overnight immersion...